# Getting error on calling JQuery AJAX for SOAP Web Service

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap, webapi

Trying to call a SOAP web service using the below mentioned code.
Seems to be hitting the error callback function

```js
var soapEnv = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><intA>3</intA><intB>3</intB></Add></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
  data: soapEnv,
  processData: false,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(res, status, xhr) {
    return;
  },
  error: function(res) {}
});
}
```

Comment: *Seems to be hitting the error callback function* and the error is.... ?

Comment: response string is blank. Error code 500. It works with Postman

Comment: Then you need to examine any logs on the server that you have to figure out what is causing the 500.